# How to assign default value or nil value for @Binding in initializer in SwiftUI View?

Tags: ios, swiftui

My View is very simple:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CategoryElementView: View {
    @Binding var selectedCategory: String?
    private let category: String
    private let isSelectable: Bool
    
    private var isSelected: Bool {
        !isSelectable || category == selectedCategory
    }

    init(category: String, selectedCategory: Binding<String?>) {
        self.category = category
        self.isSelectable = true
        self._selectedCategory = selectedCategory
    }
    
    init(category: String) {
        self.category = category
        self.isSelectable = false
        self._selectedCategory = category 
        // ❌ Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Binding<String?>'
    }
}
```

What is my purpose? I need to use the same view for 2 modes: to select it (`selectable == true`), and just to display it (`selectable == false`). And in case there is no selection, Binding from outside is not needed. How can I do it? Nil also produce an error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common case with building previews where you want to inject constant values instead of bindings. You should be able to use the same approach:

```
self._selectedCategory = .constant(category)
```

It should also work with `nil`.

```
self._selectedCategory = .constant(nil)
```

In your case you could even use a single constructor:

```
init(category: String, selectedCategory: Binding<String?>? = nil) {
    self.category = category
    self.isSelectable = selectedCategory != nil
    self._selectedCategory = selectedCategory ?? .constant(category)
}
```